# Panning a div in IE8 using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I am having problems trying to pan a div in IE8 using jQuery mousemove, mouseup, and mousemove events. Once I hit the mousedown, mousemove isn't detected until I release the mouse button and to detect mouseup, I have to hit the mouse button again.

Here is the javascript:

```
// ********** CLICK AND DRAG MAP PANNING ********** //
            var mouseDown = false;
            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseY = 0;
            var originalLeft = $("#layout").offset().left;
            var originalTop = $("#layout").offset().top;

            $("#layout").mousedown(function(event){
                mouseDown = true;
                mouseX = event.pageX;
                mouseY = event.pageY;
                originalLeft = $("#layout").offset().left;
                originalTop = $("#layout").offset().top;
                return false;
            });

            $(document).mouseup(function(){
                mouseDown = false;
                return false;
            });

            $(document).mousemove(function(event){
                if (mouseDown == true) {
                    var panLeft = (event.pageX - mouseX);
                    var panTop = (event.pageY - mouseY);
                    var left = originalLeft + panLeft;
                    var top = originalTop + panTop;

                    // Constrain the map
                    var container = $("#map");
                    var map = $("#layout");

                    if (left >= container.offset().left) {
                        left = container.offset().left;
                    } else if (left + map.width() <= container.offset().left + container.width()) {
                        left = container.offset().left + container.width() - map.width();
                    }

                    if (top >= container.offset().top) {
                        top = container.offset().top;
                    } else if (top + map.height() <= container.offset().top + container.height()) {
                        top = container.offset().top + container.height() - map.top();
                    }

                    $("#layout").offset({ left: left, top: top });
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            // ********** ********** ********** //
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="map">
    <div id="layout">
        <img src="images/map.png" alt="map"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image in the #layout div is set to be the same size of the div. I think there could be a problem with that in IE8 where it thinks I am trying to drag the image. Not sure if this is the case, though, and I thought about making it a background instead, but then I can't size it properly since IE doesn't use background-size property. If I make the image smaller to use the background, it will get blurry as I zoom in.

Comment: Does your question mean that it works fine in Chrome/FF/Safari/Opera/IE9 ?

Comment: You know there are existing scripts that can do this without reinventing the wheel? F.ex: http://aino.github.com/pan.js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you are binding `mousedown` to `#layout` and the other two to `document`. You might also want to try adding:

```
if ( 'attachEvent' in document ) {
    document.attachEvent('ondragstart', function() { return false; });
}
```

To prevent dragging in IE

Comment: If I bind mousedown to the document, then anywhere a user clicks where start panning the map and that is not what I want. If I bind mouseup and mousemove to #layout, then it creates problems when the user moves outside the #layout div.

Comment: OK fair enough. See my edit, perhaps it helps if you prevent dragging in IE.

Comment: That works. I don't plan to have any draggable elements on the page, but if I did, do you know if that would cause any problems?

I did find another potential solution that seems to work and that is to attach the attribute "unselectable=on" to the map image. I am not sure which is the better way to go. I have it detect if IE8 or less is used, attach that attribute.